# Getting SourceGuardian Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

Can anyone tell guide me on how to install SourceGuardian on bigrock.com shared hosting?

Please visit this link: http://www.crimsonbux.com/howto-install.php

Comment: A few things you could do to improve this question: first, move it here - don't write the question elsewhere and hyperlink, since links often break. Also, most people here won't know who that hosting company is - instead, specify what _kind_ of hosting it is, such as "shared cPanel Linux hosting" or "Debian 512MB VPS" etc. Also, whilst I see you've written out some steps already, can you specify where exactly you're getting stuck? What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loader wizard on the SourceGuardian site to help you to answer:

http://www.sourceguardian.com/loaders/download.php